# How to boost Kotlin+Idea+gradle?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have such a powerful laptop ThinkPad T570 i5+16gb ram. I've been working with java8 + spring boot + gradle for a long time. Several weeks ago i started using Kotlin + gradle with Kotlin DSL + spring boot. I just installed Kotlin plugin for my Intellij Idea additional. But i really see performance degradation.

When i work with java everything is ok in Intellij IDEA. But when i use Kotlin - i see freezes, auto completion works much slower than it works with java, sometimes it shows autocomplete only after CTRL+SPACE. ALT+ENTER adds imports only in 50% trying.
Working with gradle.build is impossible. Each new character entered to file  triggers whole gradle project refresh.

I hate process of programming in this way so much. It makes me very aggressive.

Ok. I understand why Kotlin compilation takes more time than java's. But what's wrong with IDEA and Kotlin compatibility? JB created language and should be crazy about the almost only IDE for this language.

Is somebody meet situation like me? How did you resolved such performance issues?

Comment: This question will get closed soon as it's not really a programming question. I'd start asking on Kotlin and Idea support groups.

Quick suggestion. Turn off auto-import for Gradle. IntelliJ will pop-up a dialog when build file changes, and you can decide when to import.

Run latest EAP of IntelliJ and of Kotlin plugin. 2013 MacBook Pro w/16GB and it's responsive. Java is faster, but Kotlin is pleasant.

Remove non-essential plugins
Ensure IntelliJ has at least 2GB of memory allotted to it
Uninstall Lombok plugin, or at least ensure it's not on for Kotlin project

Comment: @artyomkarnov We have a desktop with 32 GB i7 4cores and a high end graphics card with 16 mb  do a Alt + Ctrl + Del Kotlin is using a lot of memory

Comment: If you have automatic build import enabled in IDEA, try disabling this. It will compete with resources on your workstation while you're editing build logic.